# installing tomcat on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I know there are other answers to this I have look through it and still can't find my problem I am on a windows 10 computer

I have tomcat installed and can connect to the test site apparently I can't add images so you will just have to trust me on somethings I have eclipse installed and have the web development tools installed with it

things i have installed for eclipse

```
{
  Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle    3.0.0.v20181106-1441-m  org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
  EclEmma Java Code Coverage    3.1.1.201809121651  org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group   Eclipse EclEmma
  Eclipse IDE for Java Developers   4.10.0.20181214-0600    epp.package.java    Eclipse Packaging Project
  Eclipse Java Development Tools    3.16.0.v20181206-1038   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools   3.9.200.v201808172107   org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools  3.11.0.v201808212348    org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse Platform  4.10.0.v20181206-0815   org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
  Eclipse RCP   4.10.0.v20181206-0815   org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse Web Developer Tools   3.11.0.v201811192212    org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.12.0.v201811192212    org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Git integration for Eclipse   5.2.0.201812061821-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
  Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface  5.2.0.201812061821-r    org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse EGit
  Java implementation of Git    5.2.0.201812061821-r    org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group  Eclipse JGit
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)  1.10.0.20181127-2120    org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)   1.10.0.20181127-2120    org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  Marketplace Client    1.7.3.v20181205-1546    org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group   Eclipse Marketplace Client
  Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins    1.16.0.v20180403-2055   org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group  Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE  3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Java Development 3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task List   3.24.2.v20180905-0003   org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task-Focused Interface  3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Tasks Connector: Bugzilla   3.24.2.v20180905-0003   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Versions Connector: Git 1.16.0.v20170629-1738   org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn WikiText    3.0.25.201806201740 org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Oomph Setup   1.12.0.v20190206-0943   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group   Eclipse Oomph Project
  Tip of the Day UI Feature 0.2.200.v20181107-2118  org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group  Remain Software
}
```

if you are actually going to bother to go through that list if I am missing anything then tell me prehapse i installed the wrong one

when I go and create a new project it doesn't show up with apache when looking for a target runtime which is the folder for tomcat I get IBM ow2 oracle red hat red hat jboss middleware resin and SAP when I look inside all of the folders there isnt a tomcat

according to the videos that I watched I should be able to see an apache folder so am i missing something or need a different install

also, I did try an eclipse plugin for tomcat it said the server started up but I couldn't run any JSP code or find the target runtime apache folder

i have tried with tomcat versions 7 and 9 eclipse 4.10

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of eclipse? These tools are already bundled in newer versions. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2018-12/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

Comment: Did you go to the Server Runtimes preference page and tell Eclipse where to find Tomcat? If it has problems accepting the installed path, have you tried it with a zip/tar directly from Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **JST Server Adapters Extensions** feature mentioned at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . It contains the Tomcat support.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the tomcat zip file from the official site; most of the time version 8 or 9 will be suitable for you. extract the zip file in your pc.

open the eclipse and you will find the server view in the view menu item. create a new server with your extracted folder. I hope you get the idea. If you need more clear steps to install tomcat on eclipse please let me know. I will update this answer.

cheers...!!!